# How can i optimize this method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have products and every customer has a different discount percent for product groups. My method is basically loops all products and calculate the price for the given user and returns json. With this json I'm listing products on a mobile app. But in this current state its very slow. There are only 366 products available and it tooks like 7 seconds. You can click the link below and see how much it takes the load for you.

https://imaxon.tech/urunler/M000489

```
public function apiindex($userid)
{
     $urunler = Stok::where('StokMiktari', '>', 0)->get();
     $urunler->map(function (Stok $stok) use ($userid) {
            $user = User::where('bayikodu', $userid)->first();
            $grup = $stok->SiraNo;
            $fiyati = $stok->SatisFiyati;
            $iskonto = $user->iskontolar()->where('grup_kodu', $grup)->first();
            $iskonto_orani = 0;
            if ($iskonto != null) {
                $iskonto_orani = $iskonto->iskonto;
            }
            $iskontolu_fiyat = $fiyati - ($fiyati * $iskonto_orani) / 100;
            $iskontolu_fiyat = ceil($iskontolu_fiyat);
            $stok['SatisFiyati'] = $iskontolu_fiyat;
            $stok['file_path'] = asset($stok->file_path);
            return $stok;
   });
   return response()->json($urunler);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try pulling the `$user` query outside of the loop

Comment: @ChrisHaas tried but not significant optimization happened. maybe 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Pulling $user->iskontolar() out will also ease the work there.

Comment: Unfortunately with your variable names I can’t tell what the code does, for instance `$user->iskontolar()->where`. Does that need to be done in the loop, too, or could you grab everything once outside of the loop, and then loop over an array instead inside?

Comment: I guess $user->iskontolar() could be done outside loop = one query vs 366.... Then, inside loop search collection for necessary data.

Comment: When i moved $user->iskontolar() outside the loop it tooks 2 seconds now. Thanks for answers. Is there any other optimizasions can i make?

Comment: I don't speek 'Stok'; please provide the generated SQL.  Also, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table.